Github default working directory with variable
I am setting up a github actions and would need to pass default values to working directory instead of hardcoding but it appear I am unable to read the actual value from inputs variables, any advise where its going wrong.
name: Test

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      ENVIRONMENT:
        default: development
        type: string 
      PATH:
        default: test
        type: string 

  
defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash  
    working-directory: ${{ github.event.inputs.PATH }}  # ${{ inputs.PATH}} none worked
    
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Run Commands with various variables
        run: |
          echo "Hello World"
          echo "${{ inputs.ENVIRONMENT}}/${{ inputs.APPNAME }} "


"You cannot use contexts or expressions in this keyword."

As jonrsharpe shared in the comments above, according to the GitHub official documentation

You can use defaults.run to provide default shell and working-directory options for all run steps in a workflow. You can also set default settings for run that are only available to a job. For more information, see jobs.<job_id>.defaults.run. You cannot use contexts or expressions in this keyword.

Now, an alternative could be to set an environment variable at the workflow level, and use it in all the workflow jobs defaults.run configurations (you can also use directly the ${{ inputs.PATH }} in the jobs defaults.run.workking-directory configuration)
Example:
name: Test

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      ENVIRONMENT:
        default: development
        type: string 
      PATH:
        default: test
        type: string 

env:
  PATH: ${{ inputs.PATH }}
    
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash  
        working-directory: ${{ env.PATH }} # could use directly ${{ inputs.PATH }} here
    steps:
      - name: Run Commands with various variables
        run: |
          echo "Hello World"
          echo "${{ inputs.ENVIRONMENT}}/${{ inputs.PATH }} "

Just note that the workflow will break that way if you don't inform a valid working-directory through your input, as you don't have access to the github.workspace path yet (without using the actions/checkout)
References:

workflow run
workflow file


thanks, yes I have managed implement the same in the workflow to read from github outputs to env variabels and then pass to downstream workflows.
